# Initial value problem with Laplace transform

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries

How can I use Mathematica to resolve a Initial value problem involving Laplace-Transform?

For example:

Solve, using Laplace Transform, the following Initial value problem in [0,+∞]
$$
          \begin{cases}
           y'' - y = f(t) \\ y (0) = 0 \\ y' (0)=0
           \end{cases}
$$

$$f(t)=
          \begin{cases}
           t^2 && -1<t<0 \\ 1 && t>1
           \end{cases}
$$

Comment: Laplace transform works from t=0 on. You have input for negative time. Have you tried using DSolve? why do you have to use Laplace transform for this?

Comment: It doesn't involve any differential equation, only Laplace Trasforms, so i didn't use DSolve. Edited the question to make it clear.

Comment: This is a Cauchy Problem in the "Initial value problem" meaning; doesn't involve any Differential Equation. Some authors identify "Cauchy Problem" as "Initial value problem". Edited question.

Comment: A solution was accepted in which the right-hand side $f(t)$ of the differential equation has value $t^2$ for $0 \leq t <1$ rather than, as originally requested, for $-1 < t < 0$. Should the question be edited accordingly?

Comment: Using the Laplace transform, one obtains (or does not obtain) a solution of an ODE for positive values of `t`. If the solution is an analytical function, then the one can be extended on the whole reals (I don't go into deep .). The case under consideration is not such a case. `DSolve` and the usage of `LaplaceTransform` produce different answers for`t<0` if `f[t_] := Piecewise[{{t^2, -1 <= t < 0}, {1, t > 1}}]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure why you do not want to use `DSolve` but it works perfectly in your case.

```
f[t_] := Piecewise[ {{t^2 , 0 <= t < 1}, { 1, t > 1}}]
DSolve[ {y''[t] - y[t] == f[t] , y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0 }, y[t], t]
```

gives correct solution of your equation.

If you insist using Laplace transform in this problem, this can be done as follows,

```
lap = LaplaceTransform[ y''[t] - y[t] == f[t], t, s ] /. {y[0] -> 0, y'[0] -> 0};
sol = Solve[ lap, LaplaceTransform[y[t], t, s]];
InverseLaplaceTransform[ sol[[1, 1, 2]], s, t]
```

The answer should be

```
 E^(-1 - t) (E (1 + E^(2 t) - E^t (2 + t^2)) - E^t (2 E^t - E (1 + t^2)) HeavisideTheta[-1 + t])
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer above is not using the correct `f[t]` in the question. Here is solution using correct `f[t]`.

### Solution using Laplace

```
ClearAll[f, t, y, s];
f[t_] := Piecewise[{{t^2, -1 < t < 0}, {1, t > 1}}];
ode = y''[t] - y[t] == f[t];
ic = {y[0] -> 0, y'[0] -> 0};
lap = LaplaceTransform[ode, t, s];
solp = First@SolveValues[lap, LaplaceTransform[y[t], t, s]];
solp = solp /. ic;
solUsingLaplace = InverseLaplaceTransform[solp, s, t]
```

[image]

### Solution using DSolve

```
ic = {y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0};
solUsingDSolve = DSolveValue[{ode, ic}, y[t], t]
```

[image]

### Compare solutions showing they are the same

```
Row[{Plot[solUsingDSolve, {t, 0, 4}], Plot[solUsingLaplace, {t, 0, 4}]}]
```

[image]

But note that Laplace solution by definition is defined for non negative time. The solutions do not agree for negative time. Basically any input you had in `f[t]` for negative time, become zero when using Laplace transform. That is why solutions below agree only for positive time.

```
 Row[{Plot[solUsingDSolve, {t, -2, 4}], Plot[solUsingLaplace, {t, -2, 4}]}]
```

[image]